# Cassandra select query multiple params

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector, apache-spark-2.0

Using casssandra 2.28, java-connector3, sparks2.0.

I am trying to write a simple query with multiple select params- unable to get the syntax right.
**Single param works**

```
CassandraJavaRDD<CassandraRow> rdd = javaFunc 
                .cassandraTable("test", "tests").where("ID= ?", "1");
```

How do I do multiple params, tried multiple ways all fail:

```
javaFunc.cassandraTable("tests", "test").where("ID= ?", "1").and("Name= ?", "John");

javaFunc.cassandraTable("tests", "test").where("ID= ?", "1"+ " and "+ "Name= ?", "John");
```

Tried build statement, gives error - does not like "**eq**":

```
Statement s = QueryBuilder.select().all()
            .from("tableName")
            .where(eq("column_1", 1))
            .and(eq("column_2", 9))
            .and(eq("column_3", 50));
```

Seems like a basic 101 query, but simply cant find any suitable example code.

Comment: What error do you get back?   The CQL generated by your query builder looks valid to me:  SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE column_1=1 AND column_2=9 AND column_3=50;

Comment: If the issue is a compiler error, you may need to import eq from QueryBuilder, i.e. 'import static com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.QueryBuilder.eq;'

Comment: @Andy Thanks, com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.QueryBuilder.eq was the trick. But how do I convert this Resultset into an RDD- seems a a multistep process? Also is there no way for  does my original multi-param query- it returns a RDD and I can simply do a cassandracount on it (that is what I need for this current problem)

Answer (score 1):

So the syntax that finally worked is .where( ).where( ) **(no .and )**

```
javaFunc.cassandraTable("tests", "test").where("ID= ?", "1").where("Name= ?", "John");
```

Not sure if this is the only way or the most optimal way